# Custom ContentControl won't use ContentTemplate from ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

I have custom ContentControl called TabItem

```
public class TabItem : ContentControl
```

I have set the ContentTemplate to a dynamic resource coming from a resource dictionary

```
<TabItem Header="Search" Content="{Binding Path=SearchRibbon}" ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource SearchRibbonTemplate}" />
```

Using this approach I am utilizing the MVVM design pattern and the Content property successfuly binds to the viewmodel's... and the program builds successfuly and runs but without the content from within the datatemplate that the contenttemplate should be pulling in.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SearchRibbonTemplate">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TabGroupBox Header="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" Width="100">
                    <TabButton Width="100" Icon="{Binding Path=TemplateResource}" LargeIcon="{Binding Path=TemplateResource}" Command="{Binding Path=Commands}" />
                </TabGroupBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

If I use a content control as it is, this approach has always worked. Why wouldn't a custom contentcontrol not work with the ContentTemplate property?

Cheers.

**EDIT**

```
<Style x:Key="RibbonTabItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Ribbon_Framework:TabItem}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Group" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource RibbonTopBorderBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource TabItemFontBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="31" />
    <Setter Property="IsMinimized" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Ribbon_Framework:RibbonTabControl}}, Path=IsMinimized, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue=False}" />
    <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Ribbon_Framework:RibbonTabControl}}, Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue=True}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Ribbon_Framework:TabItem}">
                <Grid x:Name="grid" Background="#00000000" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,7,0,0">
                    <Border x:Name="border3" Margin="2,0,0,1" BorderThickness="1,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#CCFFFFFF" Offset="0" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#7FFFFFFF" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                        <Border x:Name="border4" BorderBrush="{Binding Group.BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" BorderThickness="1,0">
                            <Border.OpacityMask>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="0.981" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.OpacityMask>
                            <Border Background="{Binding Group.Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0">
                                <Border.OpacityMask>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#59000000" Offset="0" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="1" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Border.OpacityMask>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle4" Fill="#3FD2D2D2" StrokeThickness="0">
                                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#7F000000" Offset="0" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="1" />
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                </Rectangle>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                    <Grid x:Name="selectedGrid" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="2,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="{StaticResource ActiveTabBackgroundBrush}" Stroke="{x:Null}" StrokeThickness="0" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="1" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle1" Fill="{StaticResource ActiveTabBackgroundBrush}" Stroke="{x:Null}" StrokeThickness="0" Margin="1.8,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="1.2" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle2" Fill="{StaticResource ActiveTabBackgroundBrush}" Stroke="{x:Null}" StrokeThickness="0" Margin="2,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="2" />
                        <Border x:Name="border" Margin="1,0,1,2" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="2,2,0,0" Background="{StaticResource ActiveTabBackgroundBrush}">
                            <Border x:Name="border_Copy3" Margin="0" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="2,2,0,0" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ActiveTabBackgroundBrush}">
                                <Border x:Name="border_Copy4" Margin="0,0,-2,-1" BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="2,2,0,0" Background="{Binding Group.Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
                                    <Border.OpacityMask>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#3F000000" Offset="0" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="0.59" />
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Border.OpacityMask>
                                </Border>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="border1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="2" Height="2" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" CornerRadius="0,0,2,0" />
                        <Border x:Name="border2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="2" Height="2" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1,0,0,1" CornerRadius="0,0,0,2" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle3" StrokeThickness="0" Margin="7,-7,7,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="14" IsHitTestVisible="False">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <RadialGradientBrush Center="0.498,0.501" GradientOrigin="0.498,0.501" RadiusY="0.464">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#7FFFFFFF" Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1" />
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid x:Name="hoverGrid" Margin="2,0,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.ColumnSpan="1">
                        <Border x:Name="border_Copy" Margin="1,0,1,1" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="2,2,0,0" Background="{x:Null}">
                            <Border.OpacityMask>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#CC000000" Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#F7FFFFFF" Offset="0.985" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.OpacityMask>
                            <Border x:Name="border_Copy1" Margin="0" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ActiveTabBackgroundBrush}" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="2,2,0,0" Background="{x:Null}">
                                <Border.OpacityMask>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#CCFFFFFF" Offset="0" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#F7FFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Border.OpacityMask>
                                <Border x:Name="border_Copy2" Margin="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="2,2,0,0" Background="{StaticResource ActiveTabBackgroundBrush}">
                                    <Border.OpacityMask>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#7FFFFFFF" Offset="0.004" />
                                            <GradientStop Offset="0.5" />
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Border.OpacityMask>
                                </Border>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid x:Name="focusedGrid" Margin="2,0,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.ColumnSpan="1">
                        <Grid.OpacityMask>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#19FFFFFF" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Grid.OpacityMask>
                        <Border x:Name="border_Copy5" Margin="1,0,1,1" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="2,2,0,0" Background="{StaticResource ButtonHoverOuterBackgroundBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ButtonHoverOuterBorderBrush}">
                            <Border x:Name="border_Copy6" Margin="0" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ButtonHoverInnerBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="2,2,0,0" Background="{StaticResource ButtonHoverInnerBackgroundBrush}" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="PART_ContentContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="6,2,4,2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="15,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1">
                        <Label x:Name="contentPresenter" AutomationProperties.Name="{TemplateBinding Header}" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="{TemplateBinding Name}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Margin="0, -3, 0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="Auto" />
                    </Border>
                    <Grid x:Name="separatorGrid" Margin="0" Visibility="Collapsed" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="2" Grid.Column="1">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="separatorRectangle1" Fill="{StaticResource RibbonTopBorderBrush}" Stroke="{StaticResource RibbonTopBorderBrush}" Margin="0,0,1,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="1" Opacity="1" Visibility="Visible">
                            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.382" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="separatorRectangle2" Fill="{StaticResource ActiveTabBackgroundBrush}" Stroke="{StaticResource ActiveTabBackgroundBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" Width="1" Opacity="1" Visibility="Visible">
                            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#BFFFFFFF" Offset="0.329" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="0.5" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="HasRightGroupBorder" Value="False" />
                            <Condition Property="HasLeftGroupBorder" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="border3" Value="1,0,0,0" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="border4" Value="1,0,0,0" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="rectangle4" Value="0" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="HasLeftGroupBorder" Value="False" />
                            <Condition Property="HasRightGroupBorder" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="border4" Value="0,0,1,0" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="border3" Value="0,0,1,0" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="rectangle4" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="border3" Value="0,0,0,1" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="HasLeftGroupBorder" Value="False" />
                            <Condition Property="HasRightGroupBorder" Value="False" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="border4" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="border3" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="rectangle4" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="border3" Value="0,0,0,1" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Group" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="border3" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="separatorGrid" Value="-1,0,0,1" />
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="border_Copy3" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="rectangle3" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsMinimized" Value="False" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="selectedGrid" Value="Visible" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="False" />
                            <Condition Property="IsMinimized" Value="False" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="hoverGrid" Value="Visible" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsMinimized" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsOpen" Value="False" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="hoverGrid" Value="Visible" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsMinimized" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsOpen" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="hoverGrid" Value="Visible" />
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="grid" Value="#00000000" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSeparatorVisible" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="separatorGrid" Value="Visible" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="PART_ContentContainer" Value="6,2" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="hoverGrid" Value="2,0" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="selectedGrid" Value="2,0" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Indent" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource TabItemSelectedFontBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource DefaultFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource DefaultFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding Group.BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ControlStyleEmptyFocus}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using your custom item called `TabItem` instead of the built-in `TabItem` control? The tag should look like `<local:TabItem>`. Also, what is `SearchRibbon`? If it isn't an enumerable collection, it is likely that your `ItemsControl` is not finding any items to render, so the end result is nothing is displayed.

Comment: What is the type of the object you bind to the Content?

Comment: Technically you don't have to set a custom name for your custom namespace @Rachel ;)

Comment: Sorry, I removed the tags local to hopefully make the syntax cleaner when pasting it here however I forgot that there is an actual TabItem so I ended up making it more confusing... Search ribbon is an enumerable collection in the MainWindowViewModel.

Comment: @H.B. - the type is ReadOnlyCollection<RibbonViewModel> SearchRibbon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After correspondence with one of the developers that build the Fluent Ribbon library that I'm revamping, he noted that in order to achieve this design it will take more then just modifying the ContentPresenter and a full rework would be necessary. This being the case, he had suggested that building a list of ViewModels that derrive from each other's control will provide the design I am look for.

Thanks for everyones answers, but the difficult way seems to be the easy way in this scenario.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you did not define a default style for the control in `Themes/Generic.xaml` which should set the `Template` of the control to at least contain a `ContentPresenter`.

e.g.

```
<Style TargetType="local:TabItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:TabItem">
                 <!-- Usually there is also a Border which template binds the Margin, Padding, etc. -->
                 <ContentPresenter />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I have a ControlTemplate in the value of the template property of the style... your saying this should be a ContentPresenter instead?

Comment: @bl4kh4k: I say that the ControlTemplate needs to contain a ContentPresenter, otherwise the Content will not be shown. Also the TargetType on the ControlTemplate is required to make the ContentPresenter bind to the respective properties.

Comment: Hmm, so I do have Borders and grids within the ControlTemplate, of that style... so I should place just <ContentPresenter /> just before the end tag of the ControlTemplate? I don't understand why this works?

Comment: @bl4kh4k: No, *as i said*, the template needs to contain a ContentPresenter, **it does not matter where it is**, but *you need one*, it shows the Content of the TabItem.

Comment: I've just updated my question with the style... Should I then replace the Grid inside the ControlTemplate with a ContentPresenter? Sorry, but I'm still confused as to where to place it?

Comment: @bl4kh4k: Just place it where you want to have the Content. Also i would recommend you read [its documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.aspx).

Comment: Ah.... I think I get it... I'll play around with a bit, thanks for your help, I'll let you know if it works how I want it to. Cheers.

Comment: In my style, there is a Label... I have replaced it with a ContentPresenter... however the ContentTemplate still does no pull the datatemplate from the resource file.

Comment: That should not happen, did you try a very simple template like the one in my answer? Maybe you have something interfering in the template.

Comment: Basically I took the Fluent Ribbon library and am attempting to refactor it to fit my design. I've tried scaling it down to attempt this but still no luck.

Comment: Does the contentpresenter work the same way in the design I'm trying to accomplish if the the actual DataTemplate should be populating into RibbonTabControl... which is hooked up through the TabItem and ultimatelly part of the entire Ribbon... because I noticed there are already ContentPresenters within this style template.

Comment: @bl4kh4k: For stuff like `TabItems` there usually is one for the header (has `ContentSource` set to `"Header"`) and one for the `Content` (by default the `ContentSource` is `"Content"`).

Comment: Tha TabItem has this:
    <Border x:Name="PART_ContentContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="6,2,4,2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="15,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1">
                            <Label x:Name="contentPresenter" AutomationProperties.Name="{TemplateBinding Header}" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="{TemplateBinding Name}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Margin="0, -3, 0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="Auto" />
                        </Border>
Switching the Label to a ContentPresenter still does not work though.

Comment: @bl4kh4k: Did you set the `ContentSource`?

Comment: The custom TabItem does not provide the property ContentSource, I don't understand what you mean by setting it?

Comment: I don't suppose I can send you what I have... might make more sense to see the issues I'm having.

Comment: Ah, ContentSource is on ContentPresenter, now to find the right ContentPresenter, would it hurt to set them all?

Comment: @bl4kh4k: You can set the one for the `Content` to `"Content"`, but as i said, that is the default value anyway; the important thing is to set it to `"Header"` for the `Header`.

Comment: Found the appropriate ContentPresenter, <ContentPresenter ContentSource="SelectedContent" x:Name="contentPresenter" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" /> where ContentSource is set to SelectedContent as a dependency property RibbonTabControl... where RibbonTabItem creates a RibbonTabControl that holds child elements such as RibbonGroupBox. Setting Header to either the Content or ContentSource throws an error on window.Show Set property 'System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.Template' threw an exception.

Comment: Inner exception: Cannot bind properties of ContentPresenter because there is no property named 'Header' on type RibbonTabControl.

Comment: @bl4kh4k: If you have no header how do you intend to show it?

Comment: Isn't the SelectedContent property a 'header'? I can't find any examples that demostrate good usage of 'header'. Is header another style that needs to be created?

Comment: Using the original markup, as SelectedContent for the ContentSource... the function inside that control (RibbonTabControl) updates the SelectedContent inside and the base is my viewmodel... could it possibly be something else other then 'Header'?

Comment: @bl4kh4k: I don't quite get it, your original template contains a Label which binds to a `Header` property, where did that property go?

Comment: Its in a controltemplate that targets RibbonTabItem... but switching that label to a contentpresenter does not do the trick... especially how it is already set to a "Header". But that header property is merely the name associated to the tab.

Comment: If you would ike to take a look.... I'm attempting to revamp the fluent ribbon control library http://fluent.codeplex.com/ and I had already converted the RibbonTabItem as a ContentControl to do something like this: <Ribbon:RibbonTabItem Header="Search" Content="{Binding Path=SearchRibbon}" ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource SearchRibbonTemplate}" />